# dojo.form.Select onChange Not Fired

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am currently using dojo 1.7 to do the programming. I am getting stuck on onChange event for dojo.forms.Select. It seems to me that it never got fired. I tried to search on the Internet. But I am out of luck. What could be wrong? Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Code used to attached the event to dojo.form.Select:

```
var findLayerListOnChangeEvent = dojo.connect(findLayerListSelect, "onChange", function(newValue) {
doFindLayerListChange();
```

});

HTML code for the dojo.form.Select

```
<select id="findLayerList" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Select" data-dojo-props="required:true, sortByLabel:false" name="findLayerList" disabled="disabled" maxHeight=-1 style="width:150px;">
<option value="ID">Layer List</option>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is findLayerListSelect in your JS code.

In HTML code replace id with data-dojo-id.

Better write a jsfiddle with your code and I can help you fixing it.

Comment: Sandeep, thanks for your reply. I tried what you suggested. It still did not work. Here is the JS code for findLayerListSelect.

findLayerListSelect = dijit.byId('findLayerList');

Comment: pls. see the following jsfiddle I just pulled up for you. http://jsfiddle.net/4Dxxf/57/ The only difference is I guess is that you have the select as disabled in your HTML. Pls. compare and make your select box working.

Comment: I tried what you suggested in jsfiddle and it still doesn't work. I forgot telling you that the dijit.form.Select was generated programmatically. Does it really matter?

Comment: I used dijit.byID('findLayerList').setStore(dataStore) to dynamically change the dijit.form.Select.

Comment: Sandeep, I tried to use jsFiddle to write my code. It seems that it did not work. Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/xpmH2/9/.

Comment: There are a lot of JS issues regarding setStore and push methods but the changes you need to have are :  1) Add require statements for dojo elements like ItemFileReadStore 2) Use onchange instead of onChange at the bottom of your program.  Here is the fixed version of your jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xpmH2/11/

Comment: Sandeep, thanks for your suggestions. What you mentioned on setStore is probably right. I changed the way to populate the dijit.form.Select list from using dataStore to array. The way to do that is using dijit.form.Select.addOption to populate the list. Also, I used onChange (not onchange) and it worked. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I found that this latest jsfiddle didn't actually work as expected; on my browser the search for the item returned null, and the onchange handler was being registered for all dropdowns